# mirrorEnds puzzle gives no clue to error

Tags: java, string

I am attempting to solve a codingbat problem called [mirrorEnds](http://codingbat.com/prob/p139411). My solution fails but I'm not getting any useful feedback from the site, only a failed test run:

[image: failed test run image]

And my code (I changed `string` to `str` cause I'm used to the problems with "str"):

```
 public String mirrorEnds(String string) {

 String str = string;
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 int beg = 0;
 int end = str.length()-1;

 while(beg < end)
 {
   if(str.charAt(beg)==str.charAt(end))
    sb.append(str.substring(beg,beg+1));
   else
    break;

   ++beg;
   --end;      
 }

 if(beg==end)
  return str;
 else
  return sb.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine, for what it's worth (not much, I know, but I was writing it while you were finding the bug..)

```
private String mirrorEnds(String string) {
    final char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
    final int n = chars.length;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (chars[i] != chars[n - i - 1])
            break;
        sb.append(chars[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bah. I found it. Instance is "abba"

Needed to change "if(beg==end)" to "if(beg>=end)".

Answer (score 0):

```
public String mirrorEnds(String string) {
    String s = "";
    String str = "";

    for (int i=string.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        s = s + string.charAt(i);
    }

    for (int j=0; j<string.length(); j++)
    {
        if (s.charAt(j) == string.charAt(j))
        {
            str = str + string.charAt(j);
        }

        if (s.charAt(j) != string.charAt(j))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return str;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine:

```
public String mirrorEnds(String str) {
    String res = "";
    int count = str.length() - 1;

    for(int i = 0;i < str.length();i++)
    {
        if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(count))
        res += str.substring(i, i + 1);
        else
            break;
        count--;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String mirrorEnds(String string) {
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        if(string.charAt(i) != string.charAt(string.length()-i-1)){
            return string.substring(0,i);
        }
        else if(i==string.length()-1) return string;
    }       
    return "";    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While a code sample may answer the question, it's better to provide some sort of explanation behind what it is meant to do or show. It also increases your chances of getting upvotes! See [answer] for more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Making a helper method is both efficient and makes the job easier, and logic clearer, recommended strategy for beginners, dissect the logic out, then put it together, as seen in codingBat's fizzBuzz questions that build up to the real fizzBuzz. Even though there a shorter solutions, this shows the full extent of logic used.

```
public String mirrorEnds(String string) {
  String reversed = reverseString(string); //the reversed version 
  String result = ""; 
  for(int a = 0; a < string.length(); a++){
  if(string.charAt(a) == reversed.charAt(a)){ //keep going...
  result += string.charAt(a);
  }
  else if(string.charAt(a) != reversed.charAt(a)){
  break; //error, stop
  }  
  }
  return result;
}
public String reverseString(String s){
  String reversed = "";
  for(int a = s.length() - 1; a >= 0; a--){
  reversed += s.charAt(a);
  }
  return reversed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Here's my solution, hope it can help you

```
public String mirrorEnds(String string) {

  int mid = string.length() / 2;
  String s = "";


  for (int i = 0, j = string.length()-1; i <= mid; i++, j--) {

    if (i == mid) {
      return string;
    }

    if (string.charAt(i) == string.charAt(j)) {
      s += string.charAt(i) + "";
    } else {
      break;
    }

  }

  return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine. I did mine a little bit different.

```
public String mirrorEnds(String string) {
      //Create a string that we will eventually return.
      String ret = "";
      //Create a for loop that takes in chars from both ends.
      for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++)
      {
        //Create one and two characters in order to simplify it.
        char one = string.charAt(i);
        char two = string.charAt(string.length() - 1 - i);
        //If the front and back character in the iteration 
        //equal each other, then we add the character to the return string.
        if (one == two)
        {
          ret = ret + one;
        }
        //Otherwise, we end the loop because  we don't want to
        //Have a loopback problem.
        else
        {
          break;
        }
      }
      //Return the string that we are working on.
      return ret;
    }
```